# show the first event after current date on fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using fullcalendar. there is view where all of the events are listed.
Click on a event it will go to the calendar view. I have some recurring events 
on the list. Now I want that when I click on a recurring event then it will 
go to the calendar day view and display the first event after current date and the events on that day.

Hope I have explained well. Is this possible to do?

Waiting....

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Yes, probably ...

Comment: Any idea.. How?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `defaultDate` to the first event in your calendar? [Docs from fullcalendar.io here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/)

Here is the complete example:

See here demo example: https://output.jsbin.com/veceri

https://jsbin.com/veceri/edit?html,js

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.5/fullcalendar.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.5/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.5/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var events_array = [
    {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: new Date(2012, 7, 3)
    },
    {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: new Date(2012, 7, 1)
    },
    {
        title: 'Long Event2',
        start: new Date(2017, 6, 1)
    },
    {
        title: 'Long Event1',
        start: new Date(2017, 6, 5)
    }
    ]
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        events: events_array
    });

    var dateObj = new Date();
    var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
    var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
    var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

    events_array.sort(function(x, y){
        return new Date(year, month, day).getTime() -  new Date(x.start).getTime();
    });

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', events_array[0].start);

});
```

Comment: No, I didn't tried yet. But I need to jump to the next event from current date.

Comment: Is that possible? with defaultDate

Comment: Yes, simple you can set `defaultDate: '2014-06-12'`

Comment: yes, but this is the fixed value. I want to jump to the next event from current date and how can I find that? please any idea?